# passing variable into partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, partial-views

I have the following for and partial setup but i keep on getting an error, that the partial does not recognise the variable |builder|.

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @firm  do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :events do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'event_fields', :builder => builder  %>
  <% end %>

<%= end %>
```

_events_fields partial

```
<fieldset>
<%= builder.input :name, :collection => ['Applications Open', 'Applications Close', 'Traineeship Starts'] %>
<%= builder.text_field :start_at, :class => 'datepicker' %>
<%= builder.hidden_field :all_day, :value => true %>
<%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
```

any idea how i should be padding the variable across? or if in fact this is the correct way of doing it?  It would be really helpful is someone could help me understand a little more about how and why you need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell it that it is a partial view and pass in a hash to the locals option. Like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @firm  do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :events do |builder| %>
        <%= render partial: 'event_fields', locals: {builder: builder} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you're using Ruby 1.8 then:

```
<%= simple_form_for @firm  do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :events do |builder| %>
        <%= render :partial => 'event_fields', :locals => { :builder => builder } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`partial_name` would be replace with actual partial name or partial name with directory name.

We would provide the `data_object` object to the partial, available under the local variable `data_variable` in the partial and is equivalent to:

```
<%= render partial: "partial_name", locals: { data_variable: data_object } %>
```